# Extracting date from a file using regex

Tags: php, regex

I wanted to include a code in my source code to extract date from a log file which contains only this line:

```
{"sumSt":"10481","lastUpdated":"3\/7\/2012, 4:58 am"}
```

I want to extract just 3/7/2012 and nothing else.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: i didnt see `2/6/2013` anywhere in this question...

Comment: @Deepu it's hidden that's the problem with extracting it.

Comment: What's worng with [`json_decode`](http://codepad.org/CPS9703P) ?

Comment: Use http://us1.php.net/json_decode , that's much better than regex in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a valid JSON object. No need to get involved with regular expressions (at this stage). Perhaps it would be easier to parse it as such and then use the `lastUpdated` index to extract the time value:

```
$str = '{"sumSt":"10481","lastUpdated":"3\/7\/2012, 4:58 am"}';
$json = json_decode( $str, true );
$time_value = $json[ "lastUpdated" ];
```

Once you have the time value, you can use the `strtotime` function combined with `date` to format the date into what ever format you desire:

```
echo date( "d/m/Y" , strtotime( $time_value ) ), "\n";
```

References:

- [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/json_decode) - Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.
- [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) - Expects to be given a string ... will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp
- [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) - Returns a string formatted according to the given format string

Comment: Would your answer give `2/6/2013` like OP asked ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I think it is fair to assume that he quoted the wrong date.

Comment: @WayneWhitty, `2/6/2013` is far more different from `3\/7\/2012`

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran - that clearly was a typo. The objective is to extract the date from within the JSON.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Not really. It's just the same type of date format, only escaped.

Answer (score 1):

This is JSON. No need for regex when you can use [json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode):

```
<?php

$str = '{"sumSt":"10481","lastUpdated":"3\/7\/2012, 4:58 am"}';
$decoded = json_decode($str, true);
list($date, $time) = explode(", ", $decoded['lastUpdated']);
echo $date;
```

[Codepad example](http://codepad.org/zRj36Ns5).

Comment: @Lix How are you making the assumption that the JSON data will differ to the point where the code above will break?

Comment: @Lix Ha, no problem, I was very confused there for a second!

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot folks... got to know something new. i used json decode function for extracting it. here is my code snippet.

```
<? 
$json = file(DOC_ROOT."/../logs/updated.log");
$decoded = json_decode($json[0],TRUE);
list($date, $time) = explode(", ", $decoded['lastUpdated']);
?>
```